# Align <ul> in a middle of div

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, centering

I want that the text of the `<li>` will be in the middle of the `#nav_bar`. I tried to do this by `margin` and `padding` and I didn't succeed, anyone know how to do this?

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: it doesn't matter, but let say both.

Comment: For a navigation I can only suggest using `display:flex;`, you can find a nice article on css-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it has also a navigation example: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/pkwqH

Comment: @Grief-Code: Since flexbox [hasn't a *huge* compatibility yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), I wouldn't quite be so quick to recommend its use.

Comment: @jbutler483 You are totally right, no offense, but regarding the question, I do not think that he is thinking about compatibility :-)

Comment: @Grief-Code: I was only saying that using a simple solution, rather than a possibly unusable one, could be a better option to tell someone. If there's a way which avoids most (if not, all) compatibility issues, then it's *probably* the one to go for (like using the css "text-align" property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset `ul`'s default `padding`, add `text-align: center` to `ul` to center the `li`s and add some left and right `padding` to `li`s.

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align:center` http://jsfiddle.net/oktsheaw/

```
#nav_bar {
text-align:center;
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: gray;
height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#nav_bar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 40px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin; 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwaNwZ

CSS:

```
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align:center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Horizontally

You could use `text-align:center` to align horizontally.

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
  text-align:center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Vertically

You could use positioning to align vertically.

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;

}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;

  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Both

I've used positioning, although other forms would be equally as efficient.

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left:25%;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;

  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because of the height the elements were flowing outside remove the height of `#nav_bar` it will be vertically center and add text-align:center horizontally center

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home 2</li>
      <li>home 3</li>
      <li>home 4</li>
      <li>home 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```